# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Database Table error: undefined in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sqlite, promise

I am trying to store data that I created for my react native app using expo's SQLite but I am getting errors when I try to do so.

My code:

```
const savePlaceHandler = async () => {
    try {
      const newPath = await fileMoveHandler();
      const dbResult = await insertData(
        titleValue,
        newPath,
        "Dummy address",
        15.2,
        16.2
      ); //Here I am trying to store data in SQLite
      console.log("dbResult: ", dbResult); //no logs
      dispatch(placesActions.addPlace(titleValue, newPath)); //it doesn't dispatch
      props.navigation.goBack();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  };
```

From above I am trying to store data in the Database.

```
export const insertData = (title, imageUri, address, lat, lng) => {
  const promiseDB = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        `INSERT INTO places (title, imageUri ,address, lat, lng) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)`,
        [title, imageUri, address, lat, lng],
        (error) => {
          reject(error);
          console.log(error);
          throw new Error("Database Table error: " + error.message); //Error
        },
        (result) => {
          resolve(result);
          console.log("result: ", result);
        }
      );
    });
  });
  return promiseDB;
};
```

From the above code, I am getting an error whenever I send data from `savePlaceHandler` to `insertData`.

Error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Database Table error: undefined]
* helper/db.js:34:22 in tx.executeSql$argument_2
- node_modules/@expo/websql/lib/websql/WebSQLTransaction.js:69:13 in self._websqlDatabase._db.exec$argument_2
- node_modules/expo-sqlite/build/SQLite.js:16:8 in SQLiteDatabase#exec
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
WebSQLTransaction {
  "_complete": false,
  "_error": null,
  "_running": true,
  "_runningTimeout": false,
  "_sqlQueue": Queue {
    "first": undefined,
    "last": undefined,
    "length": 0,
  },
  "_websqlDatabase": WebSQLDatabase {
    "_currentTask": TransactionTask {
      "errorCallback": [Function anonymous],
      "readOnly": false,
      "successCallback": [Function anonymous],
      "txnCallback": [Function anonymous],
    },
    "_db": SQLiteDatabase {
      "_closed": false,
      "_name": "places.db",
    },
    "_running": true,
    "_txnQueue": Queue {
      "first": undefined,
      "last": undefined,
      "length": 0,
    },
    "exec": [Function anonymous],
    "version": "1.0",
  },
}
```

I am not able to figure out what does this error means also Why I am getting this?

Comment: I can't see your exact dependencies but can you confirm where does it say that your `executeSql` should take 4 parameters? All docs that I can see have at most 3 in the format of `executeSql('query_string', [param array], (tx, result) => {...callback..})`

Comment: Here, In docs, it is mentioned that they can be 4 parameter `(sqlStatement, args, callback, errorCallback) => void` for `executeSql()`. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/#sqltransaction

Comment: Fair enough but that means you have swapped the order of `callback` and `error callback`... And both callbacks take 2 parameters. First is always the transaction and then `ResultSet` object and `Error` object respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order of your callback implementation for `Transaction.executeSql` as per provided docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/#sqltransaction

```
export const insertData = (title, imageUri, address, lat, lng) => {
  const promiseDB = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'INSERT INTO places (title, imageUri ,address, lat, lng) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',
        [title, imageUri, address, lat, lng],
        (tx, result) => {
          resolve(result);
        },
        (tx, error) => {
          reject(error);
        }
      );
    });
  });
  return promiseDB;
};
```

Comment: Oh. Okay. I did it by mistake. Thanks for your help.